# Circuit current flow

Tags: voltage, resistance, voltmeter

I have a question which might be somewhat classed as newbie but I may have massively overlooked this concept and changes my understand greatly if true.

Looking at the image, the voltmeter measuring the circuit in series, what reading should I have here?

Would I have 12 volts because the voltmeter has a high resistance (even higher in comparison to the bulb), hence drops almost all of the voltage across it?

I know very little current will flow, but from a diagnostic point of view could I ascertain that the circuit is indeed intact as it flows through the bulb back to negative?

I've never thought of this in this way before and it makes a massive difference in my diagnostic strategies if this is this case.

12 volt circuit:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuZ25o.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- Let's say that your meter is only average and has a 1 MΩ input impedance on the voltmeter ranges.
- The lamp has a low resistance - say 100 Ω.
- The pair of them form a potential divider.
- If we add a pair of almost ideal voltmeters in parallel we can see that VM2 indicates that all the voltage is dropped across the voltmeter, R1, except for 1.2 mV dropped across the lamp. (VM2's reading has been rounded to two decimal places from 11.9988 V.)

Your understanding is correct.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The resistance of an ideal voltmeter is infinity so that there is no current flow from it.
In that case you would measure an open circuit in your example, there would be no current flowing and the voltage drop accross the bulb would be zero. So, you would measure 12 V.

Actually the voltmeter has a resistance but very high, 10 or 20 MΩ, so the influence is usually very small.

Answer (score 4):

Most digital voltmeters have input resistance of either 10MΩ or 1MΩ so you can redraw the circuit as follows:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhYLz4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

a) Explicitly shows the equivalent shunt resistance of the voltmeter and series resistance of the light bulb.

b) Since R1 is much larger than R(LAMP1), we can approximate LAMP1 with a short, and R1 with open circuit.

c) We move the voltmeter on the drawing to make it clear that it's just measuring the battery voltage, without any influence from the lamp. This is the same circuit as b), just in a different form.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, for the right reasons, the voltmeter shows 12V.

However, I suggest that this "new" strategy of yours is the *only* strategy. It is the correct application of the only laws that matter here, or in any circuit:

1. Kirchhoff's Voltage Law (KVL): All voltages around a loop sum to zero. In this instance, the voltage across the voltmeter and the voltage across the lamp must add to equal the voltage across the battery.
2. Kirchhoff's Current Law (KCL): Paraphrased, this tells you that the current is equal at all points around this loop, since there's nowhere for current to "branch" off somewhere else.
3. Ohm's Law: This is how you know what current is flowing - almost zero, due to the enormous total resistance around the loop, mostly within the voltmeter. I'll explain the "almost" part in a moment.

KVL, KCL and Ohm's law are the only laws in play here. Whatever other ideas you had before, and whatever strategy you had, are necessarily false if they didn't agree with this result. There's only one approach, and that is to simultaneously apply KVL, KCL and Ohm's law.

They aren't "strategies", they are ***law***. The only advances you can make in electronics is to grok them so well, and practice applying them so often, that you no longer have to think about them. They become as second nature as walking.

---

Not to confuse, but you should be very careful applying Ohm's law to an element with infinite resistance, such as an *ideal* voltmeter. That would resulting in *no* net current in the loop. By Ohm's law:

$$ I = \frac{V_{BAT}}{R_{LAMP} + R_{VOLTMETER}} = \frac{12}{\infty} = 0A $$

Knowing the current around the loop, we can correctly infer the voltage across the lamp, again using Ohm's law:

$$ V_{LAMP} = I \times R_{LAMP} = 0 \times R_{LAMP} = 0V $$

That's fine so far, no mathematical inconsistencies have arisen, but look what happens when you try to apply Ohm's law to the voltmeter itself, to find the voltage across it:

$$ V_{VOLTMETER} = I \times R_{VOLTMETER} = 0 \times \infty = ?? $$

This is undefined, and yet we know that \$V_{VOLTMETER}=12V\$. The only way to find this voltage is to apply KVL:

$$ V_{VOLTMETER} = V_{BAT} - V_{LAMP} = 12 - 0 = 12V $$

All the numbers add up, but why are we unable to use Ohm's law for an ideal voltmeter? From a physics perspective, there's a "measurement problem". Anything you use, to measure anything else, must extract some energy from the system under test in order to make that measurement. The measurement equipment *must* influence the measured system to some degree. That's why it's impossible for any voltmeter to have infinite resistance. If it didn't have *some* current passing through it, then it can't get energy from the external system, and it can't possibly know anything about the state of that system.

The best we can do is make voltmeters that have extremely high resistance, but finite nonetheless, say 10MΩ, or perhaps 1GΩ. For this reason it is incorrect to say that the voltmeter has 12V across it, and reads "12V". In reality it *must* draw a tiny current, and that tiny current *must* flow through the lamp. Perhaps it's 1nA, and the lamp must therefore have something like \$R_{LAMP} \times 1nA = 10nV\$ across it.

That's close enough to zero that the voltage across the voltmeter is very, very close to the remaining 12V, but technically it's only \$12V - 10nV =  11.99999999V\$. From that perspective, there is *always* a finite resistance in the voltmeter, even if it's huge, and always a calculable and finite current through it, even if it's tiny, and so there's always a well defined voltage to be found by applying Ohm's law.

Answer (score 2):

The reading will be, as you already guessed: 12 V.

Your volt meter will show the series connection of TWO voltages: 12 V from the battery, plus zero volt over the lamp, and 12 + 0 = 12.

The current through this circuit is very low, just enough to push the needle of the volt meter, which is very sensitive, so for all practical purposes we may say: zero ampere, so the lamp will stay dark and the voltage over the lamp will be zero.

Answer (score 0):

You circuit is a diagnostic test every electrician uses on a daily basis. You are measuring the Open Circuit Voltage of the battery (source). I am not going to draw the circuit out because it is to simple. A simple description will suffice. You have a power source, a 12-volt battery, or it could be 120 VAC. You have a load device, your circle with an X in it. For the sake of argument, you have a switch in place of where you show volt meter to switch the load device off and on.

The device quits working, and the first thing any electrician or technician is going to do is measure the voltage across the switch. If you measure supply voltage, 12-volts in this example, you know the switch is off and you have supply voltage. Close the switch and you will see 0-Volts.